# Smarty header location PHP

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

For a week I've been using Smarty Template Engine and I find it pretty cool because of its application logic and design separation. My problem for now is how to do a `header('Location: somepage.php');` using smarty? I know I can just do that in my php page, but I am doing it in my `tpl` file. This is what my code looks like..

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-4 columns">
{if isset($smarty.get.success) or !empty($smarty.get.success)}
{if ($smarty.get.success eq '')}
<div data-alert class="alert-box warning radius">
  Warning: No value found.
  <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
</div>
{else}
      <div data-alert class="alert-box success radius">
      {if ($smarty.get.success eq 'updatecontact')} 
      Contact successfully updated.
      {elseif ($smarty.get.success eq 'addcontact')} 
      Contact successfully added.
      {else}
      <?php header('Location: somepage.php'); ?>
      {/if}
      <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
      </div>
{/if}
{/if}
   </div>
</div
```

I am using zurb-foundation as my css framework. As you can see there I am using `<?php header('Location: somepage.php'); ?>` which is not appropriate with smarty. Is there a way to do that in smarty?

Comment: I think it will be a good practice to put `header` redirect inside business logic class not to the view.

Comment: I don't see why you want to do it in the tpl file. Not only breaks that cool logic and design separation you like, it's bad practice and it will probably produce a "Headers already been sent" error most of the time. Where's the problem in checking $_GET['success'] in php before processing the template?

Answer (score 1):

Do it with javascript:

```
<script>
window.location = 'somepage.php';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the code into `{php}`:

```
{php} header ('Location: somepage.php'); {/php}
```

Comment: I am also using this.. but if possible I actually don't want php tags in my php pages :D

Comment: This is not <?php  ?>. This is smarty's own php tag. You have to let smarty know that you intend it to run a PHP code, right? Read more here: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl

Comment: Yes sir I've enabled this by using new SmartyBC(); instead of new Smarty(); only. Thanks anyways.